# How to set tabindex to -1 via CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` with some input fields:

```html
<div class="container">
  <input id="input-a" type="text" name="input-a" tabindex="0">
  <input id="input-b" type="text" name="input-b" tabindex="0">
</div>
```

In special cases I have to disable this div by adding the following `.disable` class to the div:

```css
.disable {
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: .15;
}
```

This way it is no further possible to select the input fields with the mouse. However, you can still access the fields by tabbing into them via `tab` key. I have tried to add `tab-index: -1` to the .disable class, but that just gives me an `Invalid property name` in the Firefox developer tools (tabindex without hyphen as well).

Is there any way to disable the input fields **through CSS** comepletely so that no access at all can be guaranteed?

Comment: There is a extra ">" please make sure to remove it `type="text">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS is unable to rewrite `tabindex` attribute value, but `display` can help to avoid input to remain fully functional.

here is a snippet testing `display:contents` effects on inputs inside a `.disable` container, also you cannot select and copy/paste the value:

```css
.container.disabled>input:focus {
  display: contents;
  /* KILLS the focus */
}

div,
p {
  margin: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border: solid;
  background: white;
}

.disabled {
  color: red;
  background: silver;
}

kbd {
  border: 1px solid;
  background: silver;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 2px 6px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
}

h1::first-line {
  color: black;
  font-size: 1.8em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

html {
  display: grid;
  min-height: 100vh;
  place-content: center;
  background: white;
}

body {
  background: #bee;
  padding: 1em;
  border-radius: 1em;
  box-shadow: 0.25em 0.25em 0.5em;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<h1>test to disable inputs<br> even reached via tabindex</h1>
<!-- display:contents destroys the container at screen and kills input -->

<p>
  <a tabindex="0">Click 'N select some of this text and <kbd>tab</kbd> through inputs.</a>
</p>
<p>Unclickable inputs , no attribute nor pointer-events used .</p>
<div class="container disabled">
  <input id="input-a" type="text" name="input-a" tabindex="0" value="text not to modify">
  <input id="input-b" type="text" name="input-b" tabindex="0" value="text not to modify">
</div>
<div class="container">
  <input id="input-c" type="text" name="input-c" tabindex="0" value="text to modify">
  <input id="input-d" type="text" name="input-d" tabindex="0" value="text to modify">
</div>
```

---

**Disclaimer:**

Not to sure it is a good advise.

To disable your inputs **only from CSS** is not a good idea and **may break anytime**.

test/fork/play with at https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/mdaaPOx

---

Comment: Thank you for this example. I've just read a bunch about that display option since you mentioned it in your comment above, and it would be nice to have it acting like tabindex -1. However, there seem to be many possible complications with that, beginning with the recommendation that it should render `display: none` [https://drafts.csswg.org/css-display/#unbox] on input elements - although it doesn't but inject some weird tab routing behavior (at least in Firefox). Anyhow, its good to know that there would be a last exit for CSS, but I think I'll go with JS. Thank you

Comment: Since this answer is the closest to the question, which intentionally asked for a CSS solution, I'll accept it and hope, some day will bring the ability to set tabindex (or disabled) via CSS. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for your feed back, analyze. at first i was not too sure to post this as an answer, but then i decided to,  to to hear about it. About inputs that should render as display:none; , it actually does but since it looses focus right away, it shows up.Fpr the browser, even if focus is lost/not applied on these inputs , it remains somehow somewhere close to where it was supposed to be in the flow and tabbing keep going on without obvious bugs. One would think it could be a good solution, but the wise would not  ;)

Comment: Yes, tabbing forwardly seems to work, but backwards doesn't. I think there is some kind of tree, where once you've left a special branch, you can't go back.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is achievable by only use of CSS. I wasn't able to find any way of setting up the tab index value with CSS.

Only way I can image if it comes to vanilla JavaScript would be to select the elements and add the `disable` attribute (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/disabled) to the inputs:

```js
function toggleDisable() {
  const container = document.querySelector('#container');
  const inputs = container.querySelectorAll('input');

  if (container.classList.contains('disable')) {
    container.classList.remove('disable');
    inputs.forEach((input) => {
      input.disabled = false;   
    });
  } else {
    container.classList.add('disable');
    inputs.forEach((input) => {
      input.disabled = true;
    });
  }
}
```

```css
.disable {
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<h4>Container for comparison:</h4>
<div id="different-container">
  <input id="input-a" type="text" name="input-a" tabindex="1">
  <input id="input-b" type="text" name="input-b" tabindex="2">
</div>

<h4>Container we want to disable inputs in:</h4>
<div id="container">
  <input id="input-a" type="text" name="input-a" tabindex="3">
  <input id="input-b" type="text" name="input-b" tabindex="4">
</div>

<h4>Container for comparison:</h4>
<div id="different-container2">
  <input id="input-a" type="text" name="input-a" tabindex="5">
  <input id="input-b" type="text" name="input-b" tabindex="6">
</div>

<h4>Use button to disable/enable the targeted container's inputs:</h4>
<div>
  <button onclick="toggleDisable()">Toggle Disable</button>
</div>
```

Additionally, instead of adding the `disable` class you can use `:disable` pseudo class to style the elements as you want them. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:disabled)

In that case the code would look like this:

```js
function toggleDisable() {
  const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('#container input');

  inputs.forEach((input) => {
    input.disabled = !input.disabled;
  });
}
```

```css
#container input:disabled {
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-color: red;
  border: 4px solid blue
}
```

```html
<h4>Container for comparison:</h4>
    <div id="different-container">
      <input id="input-a" type="text" name="input-a" tabindex="1">
      <input id="input-b" type="text" name="input-b" tabindex="2">
    </div>

    <h4>Container we want to disable inputs in:</h4>
    <div id="container">
      <input id="input-a" type="text" name="input-a" tabindex="3">
      <input id="input-b" type="text" name="input-b" tabindex="4">
    </div>

    <h4>Container for comparison:</h4>
    <div id="different-container2">
      <input id="input-a" type="text" name="input-a" tabindex="5">
      <input id="input-b" type="text" name="input-b" tabindex="6">
    </div>

    <h4>Use button to disable/enable the targeted container's inputs:</h4>
    <div>
      <button onclick="toggleDisable()">Toggle Disable</button>
    </div>
```

Hope that helps.

**Note:** I changed the container class into id of the container, just to be more specific about what we want to disable. This solution can be also used with the class name - use `<div class="container"></div>` and then instead of `#container` selector will be `.container`. This can be used for example for grouping of the inputs if you want to apply same logic to different elements.

**Note 2:** I also change the tab indexes from zero to ascending values, so it can be easily observed what is actually happening when you tab through them.

Comment: Thanks for the hint using `:disabled`, wasn't aware of this feature.

Comment: You are more than welcome. I think this a more intended solution for this use case, rather than using `tabindex=-1`. There is a lot of things that can be used for styling and interacting with forms in the specification. The best way of knowing them, in my opinion, is to look up good implementation examples on the Internet. Good luck with it ;)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly manipulate the tabindex attribute via CSS, as it is an HTML attribute responsible for defining the tab order of elements on a page. To achieve the desired behavior of making input fields inaccessible when applying the .disable class to the container div, JavaScript is necessary. You can dynamically set the tabindex attribute to -1 on the input elements under these conditions.

Here's an example of how you can do this with JavaScript:

```
<div class="container">
  <input id="input-a" type="text" name="input-a" tabindex="0">
  <input id="input-b" type="text" name="input-b" tabindex="0">
</div>

<style>
  .disable {
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 0.15;
  }
</style>

<script>
  function disableInputs() {
    const container = document.querySelector('.container');
    const inputs = container.querySelectorAll('input');
    container.classList.add('disable');
    inputs.forEach(function(input) {
      input.tabIndex = -1;
    });
  }

  function enableInputs() {
    const container = document.querySelector('.container');
    const inputs = container.querySelectorAll('input');
    container.classList.remove('disable');
    inputs.forEach(function(input) {
      input.tabIndex = 0;
    });
  }

  // Call the functions to disable and enable inputs as needed
  // For example, you can call disableInputs() when you want to disable them.
</script>
```

In this example, the `disableInputs()` function applies the `.disable` class to the container div, effectively rendering the input elements unselectable through both mouse and keyboard interaction by setting their `tabindex` attributes to -1. Conversely, the `enableInputs()` function removes the `.disable` class and resets the `tabindex` values to 0, restoring the ability to select the inputs.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I really hoped there was a CSS way to do this, but anyhow I'm thankful for any information.